# Why is $x+I$ a root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, let $f(x)\in K[x]$ be irreducible, and let $I=(f(x))$. Why is it the case that $f(x+I)=0$? Here we are assuming $x+I\in K[x]/I$

Comment: You need to ask the question properly. If $f(x)\in K[x]$ then $f(x+I)$ does not make sense. You need to map $f$ into $K[x]/I$ first which you should say above and then use $\bar{f}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = \sum^n_{i+1}a_ix^i$. Notice that $f(x+I) = {\sum^n_{i=1}}a_i(x+I)^i = \sum^n_{i+1}a_ix^i +I = I$ because $f(x) \in I$ and $I$ is zero in $K[x]/I$ because $aI = I$ for all $a \in K[x]$.